# How to convert (.png,.bmp,.gif ) image files to .jpeg files in mvc4

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using fileupload control in mvc4 .  i need to convert all the image files  lesser than 4 MB to .jpeg format files and save it into database / folder in Application path .And if it is more than 4 MB i should compress it and save it as .jpeg files . Can anyone help me  with a sample code idea

Comment: I have tried the following link .http://mvcfileupload.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Controllers/AccountController.cs.. but it is not suitable for my project

Comment: Can you post *your* example code in your question? Nobody is here to write people's code for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
using(Image img = Image.FromFile("foo.bmp"))
{
    img.Save("foo.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

or use FromStream:

```
byte[] raw = ...todo // File.ReadAllBytes("foo.bmp");
using(Image img = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(raw)))
{
    img.Save("foo.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

This works with .bmp files.